# python - del statement executing early

Tags: python, jython

I'm a self-taught programmer with no formal training, so please forgive me in advance if this is a stupid question.

While programming in Python I found something weird:

```
from someModule import someClass

def someFunction():
    someInstance = someClass()
    print "foo"
    del someClass

someFunction()
```

This immediately dies with an unbound local variable error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'someClass' referenced before assignment
```

Commenting out the delete statement fixes the problem:

```
...
    #del someClass
...
```

and it returns:

```
foo
```

So, 2 questions:

1) the del statement is at the end of the function. Why is it being called before the bits at the beginning?

2) Why is it giving me an "unbound local variable" error? Shouldn't it be an "unbound global variable" error?

Comment: should you not be deleting the someInstance rather than someClass in this case since the class is your class definition and instance is your instance of that class

Comment: Yes, my question was more theoretical than practical... why is that statement being evaluated before the code that comes before it?

Comment: That wouldn't explain why the `print "foo"` isn't executed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `del` statement implicitly renders the name `someClass` local for the whole function, so the line

```
someInstance = someClass()
```

tries to look up a local name `someClass`, which is not defined at that point.  The `del` statement isn't executed early -- the name isn't defined right from the beginning.

If you really want to do something like this (hint: you don't), you must declare the name `global`:

```
def someFunction():
    global someClass
    ...
    del someClass
```

Comment: This answers the second part of the question, but not the first.  Worth pointing out that the error is a *syntax error* and happens at compilation time, not runtime.  That's why it seems to happen out of order.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone: I think this also answers the first part (in particular after my edit).

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone: The error is not a syntax error, and it happens at run time.

Comment: Ah yes!  I had no idea that 'del' made things implicitly local.  Makes sense now, thanks for the education!